# In C#, how can stdout be written to on an unattended server?

Tags: c#, php, redirect, stdout

I have a C# console app running on a linux server that uses Console.Write() to output its results to stdout. If I call it from the command line, it outputs its results as expected, but when I call it from php using exec or passthru, nothing is written to stdout. In fact, the documentation on the System.Console class contains this note: "You should not use the Console class to display output in unattended applications, such as server applications." What is the correct way to write to stdout in this scenario?

Comment: forget my last comment and my poor reading ;)

Comment: On the off chance that the problem was actually in something I was doing wrong with the php calls.

Comment: removed C# tag as question doesn't pertain to C#; added redirect tag

Answer (score 0):

When using the php exec command, redirect the output to an output array that you pass into it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: I double checked, but the output array is empty.

Comment: @nschrag: Can you post the code you use to call your console app?  Also, post the value of your return_var.